# What is the value of $k$ which for which $e^{-kx} = e^{kx}?$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was finding the solution of a partial differential equation, I am stuck at $e^{-kx} = e^{kx}$ to find the value of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Multiply both sides by $e^{kx}$.

Comment: Actually the value of k is i(pi).

Comment: @lhf see comments after my answer before responding.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint : take logarithms

Comment: Actually the value of k is i(pi).

Comment: @aswinsankar using the analysis in either lhf's answer or mine, the only solution is $k=0$.

Comment: @aswinsankar yes, now that i think about it, if you allow 
$k$ to be a complex number then it works.  This is because $e^{i\pi} = -1 = e^{-i\pi}.$  If however, $k$ is restricted to real numbers, then $k$ must $= 0.$

Comment: In fact, for the same reason, if $n$ is any positive integer, you can have $k = in\pi.$  This is because when $n$ is a positive integer, $n\pi \equiv (-n\pi) \pmod{2\pi}.$